# Как задать таймер-расписание на Python?

Tags: python

Делаю погодное приложение. Застрял на установке расписания рассылки.

Задача: юзер пишет время в формате "08:30" и в следующий раз в 08:30 ему должен приходить прогноз погоды.

Первое, как распарсить сообщение от юзера таким образом, что бы создалось расписание.
И второе - как, собственно, сделать это расписание?

По моему мнению должно быть примерно так:

```html
from datetime import datetime
if time_alarm == datetime.now("%Y, 08, 30, %h, %m, %s, %ms"): #сравнивается нынешнее время и заданное пользователем
    print ("prognoz na den")
```

С синтаксисом явно намудрил, но, думаю, донес свой ход мыслей.

Comment: А использовать cron для расписания?

Comment: Не думаю что вариант. Это все должно быть в процессе работы телеграм-бота. Не думаю что он подружится с cron. Да и не умею я с кроном работать.

Comment: У вас задача делиться на:
- подписка через телеграмм бота на погоду
- отправка пуш-уведомлений 

Подписываться можно в вашем боте и через крон запускать скрипт (написанный хоть на баше), который будет отправлять сообщения